# Takes too much time to boot but after OK

Tags: boot, bootrepair

One of my computer 
2gb ram 500gb Pentium dual g2020 2.9ghz
Windows 10 32bit
Is taking nearly half an hour to boot. But after boot things are super fast.. What would be the problem?

Comment: Could you tell us if there is a particular boot screen that it spends a lot of time on? It could be Windows or the BIOS and we can't tell without more information.

Comment: Half an hour to get to the desktop, or half an hour for it to become usable?

Comment: An uodate: I just reinstalled win 10.niw working fine for a day.. Second Faythe same issue kicks in... It gets stuck at the windows boot screen or just shows. A black screen after windows logo is gone... But when I am able to get into the windows everything is just perfect... No probs at all.. No use with the windows start up.. It shows no help.. And BTW it's just reinstalled no software's installed to startup at boot...  Sorry for the late reply... Please do help thanks...

Answer (score 2):

If you stuck in the POST process, then it could be a fault from BIOS or hardware. I would recommend checking again the BIOS settings or take a look at your hardware again.

If it takes too long to boot and stuck in Windows load process, then you should take a look again startup items. Those things are the reason that make your computer boot slow.

Go to Task Manager -> Startup Items and disable unnecessary apps.

Comment: An uodate: I just reinstalled win 10.niw working fine for a day.. Second Faythe same issue kicks in... It gets stuck at the windows boot screen or just shows. A black screen after windows logo is gone... But when I am able to get into the windows everything is just perfect... No probs at all.. No use with the windows start up.. It shows no help.. And BTW it's just reinstalled no software's installed to startup at boot...  Sorry for the late reply... Please do help thanks...